# What's the best page title in mobile applications?

Tags: mobile-application

What's the best practice for setting the title of AppBar in mobile applications? Should it represent the title of the application or should it be the title of the page?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A title is what the page is about--it describes the page. If the page is about the application, you can make that the title. If the page is about something else, make the title "Something Else".

Comment: Correct @Rob. The straight answer: the title of the page. IMO, once a user is in the App, the user does not need to be reminded what the name of the App is. That is why the title of the application is not necessary. Kind of like putting the title of a book on every page of the book.